# How to match parameter and replace the value after "=" separator

Tags: text-processing, perl

the perl one liner command to replace Value in file is simple:

```
perl  -i  's/oldval/newval/g' file.txt
```

but what should be the perl one liner syntax in case we want to replace the  value on specific parameter ( value is after "=" seperator

**Example**

We want to match the **VIP_IP** string and replace the value after "=" separator with other value as **192.17.200.100**  ( with perl one liner syntax )

```
more file.txt

VIP_IP=172.17.200.15

if [[ $VIP_IP = $HOST_IP ]]
then

.
.
.
```

Expected results

```
more file.txt

VIP_IP=192.17.200.100

if [[ $VIP_IP = $HOST_IP ]]
then

.
.
.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Include the key in your regexp.

If you know exactly how it is written, then you can use a positive lookbehind assertion and it's easier:

```
perl -pi -e 's/(?<=^\$VIP_IP=).*/192.17.200.100/' your_file
```

Otherwise, you must include the matched key in the replacement text using `$1`:

```
perl -pi -e 's/(^\$VIP_IP\s*=).*/$1192.17.200.100/' your_file
```